# Debian 9.6 not using static IP defined in interfaces

Tags: debian, ip

I have the following configuration:

```
root@pihole:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug enp0s4
iface enp0s4 inet static
address 192.168.2.225
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
```

The IP is somehow getting assigned to 192.168.2.110 when it should be .225:

```
root@pihole:~# systemctl restart networking.service
root@pihole:~# ifconfig
enp0s4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.110  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::2a0:98ff:fe2a:67fe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:a0:98:2a:67:0e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5322438  bytes 1348940213 (1.2 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 333698  bytes 66021804 (62.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Any suggestions why this is? This configuration was working... then sometime a few days later it changed to .110.

Edit: Adding output of 'ip a' command, as this shows the IP is set as 'secondary':

```
2: enp0s4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:a0:98:2a:67:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.110/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global enp0s4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.2.225/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary enp0s4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2a0:98ff:fe2a:670e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: What is the status of `ifup@enp0s4.service` and of `systemd-networkd.service`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? It shows 'up' in ifconfig.

Comment: I've also added the output of "ip a" which shows the .225 IP as secondary... I have no idea what this means